Can't close a sctp socket with linux close() function, the fd was released but the socket hanged
My app worked as a SCTP server, there are many SCTP clients connected to the server, we close the socket when the link faulted(such as heartbeat timeout), sometime the close does not work, the socket hanging in the OS, you can find it with netstat command, but without process id, the process id show "-", and I find the fd of the socket was already released, it was already reused by other connection, I do a tcpdump capture on the hanged socket, there were SCTP heartbeat message, the server send heartbeat to client, the client respond with heartbeat ACK message. At first I think it was a concurrent problem, so I delay 10 seconds to close the socket, there was no read or write on the socket when I close it, but the delay can not fix the issue.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
